# Storing functions/ equations in an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Below is a simple example of the code I am trying to implement (using it as proof of concept). I am trying to make an array `(d)` with 5 functions/equations and incrementing with `i` and at each slot of `i`. When I run the code the `"i"` in the `x/i` term is not incrementing with the for loop.

I am trying to have the output of this code an array and each term in the array =  `[x/1, x/2, x/3, x/4, x/5]`. Below is the code.

```
for i = 1:5

    d{i} = @(x) x/i

end
```

Comment: Why would you want this? There usually is a better solution than an array of functions, especially if these functions can be generated in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subs()` (symbolic substitution) function to force variable `i` to be evaluated/substituted in the equation. The `matlabFunction()` function can then be used to ensure the results are in the form of function handles/anonymous functions.
[image: Array Results]

```
for i = 1:5

    d{i} = matlabFunction(subs(@(x) x/i,i,i));
    
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**